# How to upgrade AWS API Gateway endpoints without API interruptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have been tasked with  upgrading the servers / endpoints  that our AWS APIGateway uses to respond to requests. We are using a VPC link  for the integration request.  These servers are hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

We only use two resources / methods in our API :   /middleware  and   middleware-dev-4  that go through this  VPC link.

As our customers rely heavily on our API I can not easily swap out the servers.  I can create  new servers and point the APIs to those but I do not want any downtime in our API service.  Can you recommend a way to do this API change without impacting our customers ?

Iv'e seen several examples using canary release but they seem to pertain to Lambda functions and not VPC links with EC2 servers as endpoints.

Edit --

AWS responded and they agreed that I should add the new servers to the target group in the network load balancer and deregister the old ones.

Comment: if you found my answer useful please check it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to update servers or endpoints?

If endpoints, api gateway has stages, your customer uses endpoints published on some stage. Make your changes & publish new stage, api gateway will publish new endpoints after some seconds.

If servers, then api gateway has not much to do with it. It's up to you how you run the servers. Check AWS Elastic Beanstalk blue/green deployments:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

> Because AWS Elastic Beanstalk performs an in-place update when you
> update your application versions, your application might become
> unavailable to users for a short period of time. To avoid this,
> perform a blue/green deployment. To do this, deploy the new version to
> a separate environment, and then swap the CNAMEs of the two
> environments to redirect traffic to the new version instantly.

By the way, check your **DNS cache** settings. DNS Cache may lead to real issues & downtime. If you will change CNAME value on DNS, make sure your client is not caching that CNAME value for a long time. Check what is DNS cache for that cname now, you will need that time period, so make sure to check. Update DNS to have minimum cache time, like 1 or 5 minutes. Wait the time period what was set for cache originally. Do your blue/green, update CNAME, wait for DNS cache time to expire the cache.

Comment: I need to update the servers. I think the CNAME swap could work for me although the VPC link goes through a load balancer with target groups. Maybe I can create a new target group with the new servers and then deregister the old servers.

Comment: google for blue/green deployment for your setup. You don't want to remove old servers during the upgrade. Also keep old running after migration for some time, because of networking cache. There will always be some requests to old, some to new till cache is cleared everywhere. If my answer was helpful, please accept it

Comment: Ok will confirm with AWS support for verification and will report back.